# Ignoring the where condition if null

Tags: php, yii, yii2

```
$name=Yii::$app->request->post('name');
$address=Yii::$app->request->post('address');

if($name || $address)
{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM studentrecords WHERE name=$name AND address=$address" ;
    $display=Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
}
```

What i need is if i donot input address in address field ignore `WHERE address=$address`. Currently, if `$address` is null, it gives sql error.

Comment: Your use of OR in the if statement and then AND in the query should give you a hint.  Logically, it would make sense to do those with the same operator, no?  Note that php, treats `False, null and 0` as false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You can simply do this. use `concatnation` of `$sql`. If `$name` and `$address` exist

```
$name=Yii::$app->request->post('name');
$address=Yii::$app->request->post('address');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM studentrecords where 1 = 1 ";        
if($name)
{
    $sql.=" AND name='$name'" ;

}
if($address) {
     $sql.= " AND address= '$address'";
    }

$display=Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have activeRecord you can you  `andFilterWhere`

```
         $query = StudentRecors::find()
                ->andFilterWhere(['=', 'name', $name])
                ->andFilterWhere(['=', 'address', $address])->all();
```

andFilterWhere manage the where condition in way that the part of where is added to the query only if the related value is not null

Comment: this is informative.  but for some reasons i need values in array.

Answer (score 0):

check this......

```
 $name=Yii::$app->request->post('name');
    $address=Yii::$app->request->post('address');
    $conditions = array();
    $where = '';

    if ($name) {
      $conditions[] = 'name= "'.$name.'"';
    }
    if ($address) {
      $conditions[] = 'address= "'.$address.'"';
    }

    if(count($conditions)) {
      $where = 'WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $conditions);
    }

    $sqlStatement = 'SELECT * FROM studentrecords '.$where;
```

Comment: If no name and no address are present, query will fail ;). do something like $where = ''; if(count($conditions)) { $where = .... } I have done some edits